# Saving dropdownlist selected value to ViewState

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, viewstate, selectedindexchanged

I have a dropdownlist that when changed will save the new value into a ViewState variable, so that after a postback, the dropdownlist will retrieve it's selected value from ViewState if previously set.

When it tries to store the selected value in DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged to ViewState, it always inserts the original value and not the updated one. In this case, the ViewState is always "R" and never changes according to other selected values.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication11
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ViewState["List1_Value"] != null)
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = ViewState["List1_Value"].ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "R";

        }

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["List1_Value"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }       

}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with saving to viewstate? Is it not always R because the if statement is returning FALSE?

Comment: the if Statement returns false on first page_load. Then when the selected value is changed, ViewState saves the list value but only the original "R", never a different value that was selected to fire the SelectedIndexChanged. Second time round, the if statement is true and the list retrieves it's value from ViewState, which annoyingly is still "R", since the selectedIndexChanged doesn't save the new selected value to ViewState.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Page_Load method to bypass the dropdown list code when it is not a post back.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (ViewState["List1_Value"] != null)
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = ViewState["List1_Value"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "R";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Page_Load event fires before the SelectedIndexChanged event. When you change the value in the dropdown list, the vale of the ViewState is still null so the dropdown list is set to "R"?

Tale a look at the following MSDN article discussing page life cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: ok, but the second time round the ViewState has a value of "R" which means that ViewState was saved before the page reloaded. Just need to figure out how to get a different value into ViewState?